# how to put bullet point in the form access?

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have to design dataentry form in access 2013. user wants to have this possibilty that entering  data in a feild and this feild automatically put bullet.
Is there any way I can set the field so that it defaults to bullet point?

I searched about it  and I found : I should change datatype of this feild to long text in the TABLE and I changed text format to rich text in the TABLE and FORM. 
then I should change default value of text box to

```
"<ul></li>"
```

in the FORM. 
if I earse content of field then I loose this formatting ,I want to have just bullet format in this field not normal text , is this any way to force this field to bullet?

Comment: You also need to change the text format to rich text in the textbox in the FORM.

Comment: I did it and I got bullet but if I erase all contents of the box then I loose this formatting. what should I do to force this field have format of bullet ?

Answer (score 1):

Insert a label at the left end of the line, type the letter l (lowercase el) as the caption, change to Wingdings font.